# RESPONSE_SERVER rewrite rule not working for all response headers

Tags: c#, iis, url-rewrite-module

I have a asp.net website called Home running in IIS and I added a rewrite URL rule to change the server tag in the response header to Mine. It only works for some of the responses and not all of them.

For example:
https://myDomain/Home/Default.aspx works. (Server: Mine)
But https://myDomain/Home/ does not work (Server: Microsoft...)

The code of my rule that can be found in C:\Windows\System32\inetsrv\config\applicationHost.config are the following:

```
<rewrite>
        <allowedServerVariables>
            <add name="RESPONSE_SERVER" />
        </allowedServerVariables>
        <globalRules>
            <rule name="Remove Server">
                <match url=".*" />
                <serverVariables>
                    <set name="RESPONSE_SERVER" value="Mine" />
                </serverVariables>
                <action type="None" />
                <conditions>
                </conditions>
            </rule>
        </globalRules>
    </rewrite>
```

I am removing the server version for security reasons, but if it does not work for all responses, it defines the point.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As far as I know, if you want to modify the reponse header's value. I suggest you could try to use url rewrite outbound rule instead of normal rule.

Please add below rule in the application.host file:

```
<rewrite>

    <allowedServerVariables>
        <add name="RESPONSE_SERVER" />
    </allowedServerVariables>
    <outboundRules>
        <rule name="ModifyServer">
            <match serverVariable="RESPONSE_SERVER" pattern=".*" />
            <action type="Rewrite" value="Mine" />
        </rule>
    </outboundRules>
</rewrite>
```

Comment: It did solve my problem that I stated above, but there are still one response type from the server that contains the server version :  https://myDomain/Home/WebResource.axd which gets returned if I go to either"https://myDomain/Home/Default.aspx" or "https://myDomain/Home/". I researched and found that it is resource files generated by asp.net. Will find out if I can remove that response or remove the server tag from it.

Comment: The WebResource.axd responses was cached, so when I cleared my cache, it worked. Now it works perfectly.

Comment: It does not work to rewrite Server information for responses from SSRS.